# Make vertical images menu

Tags: css, jquery-animate

I'm having a **hard time** making a vertical menu using images.

There are **5 images** and I want to show all them in a "collapsed" mode, and upon clicking, the clicked image should expand and other collapse to make room for it.

I'm almost there: http://jsbin.com/eyepam/2/

But I can't make it work perfectly as:

- the menu **never expands** to the full available width (there's always a white margin on the right)
- animation is **not smooth enough when resetting the sizes**, I would love to make the animation a littler smoother than it is (it looks like it rests all first and then expand the clicked one, the idea was to expand the clicked one and collapse all others... smoothly)

Can any one that has a better knowledge of CSS help me get there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check out my solution here](http://jsbin.com/eyepam/19/)

jQuery code:

```
var winWidth = $(window).width(),
    activeWidth = winWidth / 2,
    nonActiveWidth = (winWidth - activeWidth) / 4 ;

$(function () {
  $("ul li")
    .height($(window).height())
    .click(function () {

      $(this) // expand active one
        .animate({ width: activeWidth , queue: false});
      $("ul li") // collapse others
        .not(':eq('+$(this).index()+')')
        .animate({ width: nonActiveWidth , queue: false});
    });

});
```

I moved the width adjustments to the CSS:

The important part, use of `box-sizing:border-box` so that the border appear as 'inner-borders' and hence it doesn't disturb our calculations of the `<li>`'s widths at all.

```
.container ul li {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  border-left: 4px solid #000;
  height: 768px;
  -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing:         border-box;   
}
```

Comment: ohh lovely, thanks. BTW do you know how can I make everything "fullscreen" so that white space at the right does not show up? I tried `overflow: hidden` but it always append the last `li` in the bottom :/

Comment: I am trying to check this one out at the moment :)

Comment: Fixed the calculations so that border-width doesn't affect the widths of <li>s. Hope it fits to your needs :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the work, I would never remembered to use `box-sizing`! :o)